# How to check or uncheck the radio button according to value in php?

Tags: php, session, radio-button

I am stuck on the issue.
I have two radio buttons. One is a `Buyer` and the second is the `Seller`.

```
 <input type="radio" name="account_type" value="1" id="acc_buyer" checked="checked">Buyer
 <input type="radio" name="account_type" value="2" id="acc_seller">Seller
```

The Buyer radio button is already checked.

Now What I am doing is, I have the below code, and if the `$account_type==2` then I have to select the `seller` radio button and unchecked the buyer.

I tried the below code

```
 if(isset($_SESSION['error'])){
    $error = $_SESSION['error'];
    $account_type = $_SESSION['account_type'];
    unset($_SESSION['account_type']);
    unset($_SESSION['error']);
}
 
 <input type="radio" name="account_type" value="1" id="acc_buyer" checked="checked"> Buyer
 <input type="radio" name="account_type" value="2" id="acc_seller" <?php if(isset($account_type) && $account_type=='2') { ?> checked="checked" <?php }?>> Seller
```

Comment: You placed `checked` on both of the radio buttons. If they depend on a value, they should both be output based on a condition.

Comment: @El_Vanja, You are right but I am not able to uncheck the buyer. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the correction with the added `empty()` check.

```
$checked = [];
$checked[0] = empty($account_type) || (isset($account_type) && $account_type == 1) ? 'checked' : '';
$checked[1] = isset($account_type) && $account_type == 2 ? 'checked' : '';

<input type="radio" name="account_type" value="1" id="acc_buyer" checked="<?php echo $checked[0] ?>">
<input type="radio" name="account_type" value="2" id="acc_seller" checked="<?php echo $checked[1] ?>">
```

Comment: Let me check this. Give me sometime

Comment: I checked, When I reload the page then I am getting the Seller checked. It should be Buyer

Comment: Is this correct? 1) On a fresh page load, buyer should be selected as a default? 2) Seller should be selected if after page load, the user clicks seller, then submits?

Comment: NO, 1 point is correct. For the 2, If the session is activated and account_type is 2 then select a seller or else select buyer.

Comment: I am still getting the seller selected when reloading the page.

Comment: That's what you said above for #2) If the session is activated and account_type is 2. That is exactly what `isset($_SESSION) && $_SESSION['account_type'] == 2` this line states.

Comment: Yes but the session is not active from my side still now. Let me clear all the history and try.

Comment: I clear the history, and  I refresh the page. So initially I have to show the buyer radio button checked. (note: session is not active yet.)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['error'])){
    $error = $_SESSION['error'];
    $account_type = $_SESSION['account_type'];
    unset($_SESSION['account_type']);
    unset($_SESSION['error']);
}
?> 
<input type="radio" name="account_type" value="1" id="acc_buyer" checked="checked">
 <input type="radio" name="account_type" value="2" id="acc_seller" <?php if($account_type==2){echo 'checked="checked"';}?>>
```

Comment: I am not getting $account_type==1 from anywhere.

Comment: you can replace value accordingly. But this is the basic working example

Comment: this has the potential for `checked=checked` on both radios.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I don't duplicate other's answers and my solution isn't unnecessary, but I used this code snippet:

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['error']))
{
    $error = $_SESSION['error'];
    $account_type = $_SESSION['account_type'];
    unset($_SESSION['account_type']);
    unset($_SESSION['error']);
}
$account_type_set = isset($account_type);
$buyer = $account_type_set ? ($account_type == 2 ? 0 : 1) : null;
$seller = $account_type_set ? !$buyer : null;
?>
 <input type="radio" name="account_type" value="1" id="acc_buyer" <?php if($buyer) { ?> checked="checked" <?php }?>> Buyer
 <input type="radio" name="account_type" value="2" id="acc_seller" <?php if($seller) { ?> checked="checked" <?php }?>> Seller
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: What I did, I am checking the `$account_type` is empty then add checked. So I am getting a buyer checked.

I don't know this is the best answer or not but it's solved my issue.

I tried

```
if(isset($_SESSION['error'])){
        $error = $_SESSION['error'];
        $account_type = $_SESSION['account_type'];
        unset($_SESSION['account_type']);
        unset($_SESSION['error']);
    }

<input type="radio" name="account_type" value="1" id="acc_buyer" <?php if(empty($account_type)){?> checked="checked" <?}?>>Buyer

<input type="radio" name="account_type" value="2" id="acc_seller" <?php if( isset($account_type) && $account_type=='2'){?> checked="checked" <?}?>>  Seller
```

Comment: This is basically like the first solution I provided... good thing it's working for you

Comment: empty($account_type) was missing from your answer. Please update your answer. I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Answer modified to include `empty()` check. Thanks